# vue-loader: Module was not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, package.json

I can't find the issue for this **module was not found** error.

> This relative module was not found:
>
> - ./graphics/logo.svg in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"259fb446-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=template&id=8dc7cce2&scoped=true&

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-flickity": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.19",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^4.4.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

I'm using **@vue/cli@3.11.0**.
I tried multiple times deleting package-lock.json/node_modules and running npm install afterwards. Nothing fixes it - even updating Vue CLI and all packages globally.

Comment: Is ./graphics/logo.svg present in your projects folder?

Comment: @madflow yes you're right, the error it's not about a missing svg loader

Comment: Yes it is present in the folder.

Comment: Since you have already done what the docs say https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#caching-and-parallelization by deleting node_modules - the remote debugging skills end for me. I would need some code like a minimal repo with the code in question. Maybe disable the cache-loader completely and check if the problem still persists?

Answer (score 3):

Put the images in the src/assets folder, and type like this
`<img src="~@/assets/images.jpg/>`